# chinese language use in solaris 10 and redhat 6

Tags: solaris, redhat-enterprise-linux

How  to type in Chinese in solaris 10 and redhat 6 ?
Please tell method how to configure it through command line not through GUI

Answer (score 0):

You must install the language support for this operating systems. For example, take a look on [add language discussion](http://www.unix.com/solaris/119035-add-language-en_us-solaris-10-a.html).